# Change name box of a image inserted into excel worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, vba

When you insert a picture into a excel worksheet, you get automatically Picture 1, Picture 2, and so forth...... I have a function when a picture is selected to put black border around it. Problem is, if I have two picture on worksheet that is named Picture 1, the function will not know which picture 1 to put the border around thus may put border around the incorrect selected image.

Here's my code to put border on image:

```
Private Function AddImageBorder(WhichSheet As String)

With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(WhichSheet).Shapes(Selection.Name)
    .Line.Weight = 5
    .Line.Visible = msoTrue
End With
```

End Function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a simple solution to this would be to rename your images. How you get two "Picture1" is beyond me, I had to rename one in VBA. Anyway here is a way to number your shapes so none overlap -

```
Sub NumberShapes()
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim i As Long
    i = 1
    For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        shp.Name = "Picture" & i
        i = i + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

Personally, I would do it differently by identifying what it is first.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub NumberShapes()
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim i As Long
    i = 1
    For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    If shp.Type = msoPicture Then
        shp.Name = "Picture" & i
        i = i + 1
    ElseIf shp.Type = msoChart Then
        shp.Name = "Chart" & i
        i = i + 1
    ElseIf shp.Type = msoTextBox Then
        shp.Name = "Textbox" & i
        i = i + 1
    End If
    Next
End Sub
```

With this solution you get to decide what they are called based on what their [type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff860759.aspx) is.